# Google plus: Over-the-air install does not prompt to my app

Tags: google-plus, over-the-air

I have created a project in google console and I have added the functionality to log in by using gplus.

```
var render = function () {
        gapi.signin.render('button_gplus', {
            'callback': 'signinCallback',
            'clientid': '281111190795-qitnk6n5ccnd7lo0koqahar9snmor2mn_dot_apps_dot_googleusercontent.com',
            'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
            'accesstype': 'offline',
            'apppackagename': 'com.cuble.vittaliamarket',
            'scope': scopes
        });
    };
```

Logging in works fine.

Everything is placed where it is supposed to be, but when logging in with my device it doesn't prompt to Google Play and it doesn't provide my app from Google Play. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. I have created a project in Google APIs Console and I have also created a client ID for web applications and a client ID for installed applications. It has also the deep linking enabled. They are all under the same project. Do I need to register my project to get it work properly? Does it completely neccesary? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app wont show if you already have it installed under that account.

Looking at your app though, I would guess its being limited under the "quality" restriction - there are some filters that make sure bad apps don't get pushed to users, and there needs to be a certain (unspecified) number of reviews for the quality decision to be made.

Comment: Thanks Ian, that was my first guess. But how do I know my app exceeds (or doesn't) quality threshold? My app is published in the Market and google never complained. Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, I have not my app installed in the devices I'm using for testing

Comment: I would say it'll just start working once you've got some more reviews - at the moment the judgement isn't that it's low quality, it's just that there's insufficient data.